# CSS vertical list with auto width and margin between cells

Tags: html, css

I need to create vertical list of items or vertical menu which has width set to width of the longest item.
Here is `table` based version https://jsfiddle.net/fj8z6r33/:

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="2">
    <tr><td>item 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>item 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>long item 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>very very long item 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td {
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

But solution based on table suffers from some level of rigidity and requires to use outmoded `cellspacing` attribute, so is it possible to make same thing using divs or ul/li.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're creating a list so should use list items. https://jsfiddle.net/fj8z6r33/1/

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 6px 18px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>long item 3</li>
  <li>very very long item 4</li>
</ul>
```